# how can i change key,value format back to lines?

Tags: python

file_name.txt contains

```
{'email1234': 'OK', 'email03': 'SPAM', 'email02': 'OK', 'email01': 'OK'}
```

My code

```
def write_classification_to_file(fpath1,fpath2):

    f = open('file_name.txt', "r")
    xs = f.readlines()




    g = open('file_write.txt', "w")
    for v in xs:
     g.write(v)
    return g
```

i am trying to write the text in filename.txt to file_write.txt but by removing the key and value of file_name.txt and joining it together so far i managed to print it there but same as file_name.txt i got

expected input in file_write.txt

```
email01 OK
email02 OK
email03 SPAM
email1234 OK
```

Comment: Clarify what you want. Having a file called file1 and a dictionary file1 is confusing. What is your desired output and what is your input?

Comment: i just edited my post

Comment: iam sorry my mistake i meant they are same

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't get what you actually want. You have one file or two? What do you want to join and what do you want to exclude?

Comment: i have a .txt file contains the above given in the first line and i want to write its contants in to another .txt file which is file_write.txt but file_write should not be in a dictionary same as file_name ,, it must be same as the expected output above

Comment: your dictionary is named `filename.txt` and you are trying to open it as a file which you can't do. Post a sample of your file that you are trying to read

Comment: yes you are right i edited my post , i meant its inside that the file_name.txt

Comment: its woring with me but its just writing the same dictionary of file_name to file_write how can i make it be written same as the expected input in file_write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file doesn't seem to be strictly json format, but `ast.literal_eval` will process the Python dictionary syntax:

```
import ast
with open('file_name.txt') as f:
    D = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
with open('file_write.txt','w') as f:
    for k,v in D.items():
        f.write('{} {}\n'.format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
email02 OK
email1234 OK
email03 SPAM
email01 OK
```

You can use `for k,v in sorted(D.items()):` if the key ordering matters.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what part of it isn't strictly json format? Single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: @TomDalton I think json.loads() works well only with double quoted strings. `{'email1234': 'OK', 'email03': 'SPAM', 'email02': 'OK', 'email01': 'OK'}` did not work but `{"email1234": "OK", "email03": "SPAM", "email02": "OK", "email01": "OK"}` did
`

Comment: @TomDalton, `json.load` failed on the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably json decoding.

```
import json
def write_classification_to_file(file_name_in, file_name_out):
    with open('file_name.txt', "r") as f_in:
        xs = json.loads(f_in.read())
    with open('file_write.txt', "w") as f_out:
        for key in sorted(xs.keys()):
            f_out.write("{} {}\n".format(key, xs[key]))
```

Comment: This will only write the keys of `xs` to the file. The OP says the key as well as the value is desired. You're also returning the file object which I'm not sure is good idea, ir even wanted.

Comment: well i write `g.write(v)` and `g.write(xs[v])` that should already write both.

Comment: My mistake, I did't notice that since you are doing it in a very unusual manner. Would in be easier to use `for key, value in xs.items()` and then just `'{} {}'.format(key, value)`

Comment: Note that by parsing it into a python dict, the order of the items in the file will not be preserved. From the OP, it seems like the order is expected to be reversed?! Or maybe sorted, which makes your life easier :)

Comment: i got an error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'list'

Comment: I edited the answer. I now use read() not readlines(). @IanAuid I thought writing it like that might be a bit easier to understand although it is not that pythonic as your suggestion.

Comment: The function arguments must be variable names, not strings.